# Is there a way to send amp form data to google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

There are ways to add html form data to spreadsheet, but can amp-form data can also be sent to spreadsheet. I tries by using this simple method https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/721795/Store-your-form-data-in-Google-Spreadsheet

Here's the form

```html
<amp-script width="1" height="1" script="webSocketDemo"> </amp-script>
<form name="contact">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <input class="input-label" type="text" name="Name" data-form-field="Name" placeholder="Name" required="" >

        <input class="input-label" type="phone" name="Mobile" data-form-field="Phone" placeholder="Phone" required="" >

        <input class="input-label" type="email" name="Email" data-form-field="Email" placeholder="Email" required="" >
        <select name="Course">
            <option value="">1</option>
            <option value="">2</option> 
            <option value="">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="align-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary display-7 display-6" id="ButtonSubmit" onclick="postContactToGoogle()" >Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the js

```js
function postContactToGoogle() {
    var email = $('#Email').val();
    var name = $('#Name').val();
    var mobile = $('#Mobile').val();
    var course = $('#Course').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSe430g_JJ5AjWF-VZRfo7xRAhUBB8a2tUcFIg8afBIgCsQh3Q/formResponse",
        data: { 
            "entry.142451696": email,
            "entry.929775569": name, 
            "entry.1001360739": mobile, 
            "entry.2049253971": course 
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        statusCode: {
            0: function () {
                window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
            },
            200: function () {
                window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any proper solution out there?